# Battlefield framerate: is my CPU or GPU the bottleneck?

Tags: battlefield-3, battlefield-4

I have a similar problem with Battlefield 3. In BF3, no matter what I do, the framerate will be in the 15-40fps range. 60fps only if I look into the sky. If I have everything at low and at 640x480, I can't get a stable 60fps going.

I have the same problem with BF4. Am I CPU bound? I have a A4-5300, which I found out has no L3 cache and only 1mb of L2 cache. I have 4gb of system memory and a Geforce 650 GTX. Am I just bottle-necked?

***UPDATE***
Just as a follow up, I went from the dual core AMD, to a "quad" core AMD. The quotations marks are there because AMD is a little shady about what they mean with cores. The quad core AMD performed much better and BF3 and 4 became playable, but the FPS still struggled more than I thought it would, but it was playable. I recently said screw it, bought a i7 4790k Devil's Canyon CPU and now things are perfect. I still have a modest Radeon 270 2gb, but the performance is excellent on all high. BF3 and 4 just demand a solid CPU, mine is overkill now, but you must have a true quad core!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bring down the console with the <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde) key and type

`render.perfoverlayvisible 1`

[image: render.perfoverlayvisible 1]

Leave that up while playing. What you're looking for here is spikes that show you what the bottleneck is: CPU (yellow) or GPU (green).

Answer (score 1):

The A4-5300 is a dual-core 3.2Ghz CPU. I wouldn't want to try and run BF3 or 4 on a dual-core chip, a quad core at least. 4GB and GTX 650 should be fine. Have a look at CanIRunIt - systemrequirementslab.com/cyri - and see what it says about your system.

Comment: Does BF4 actually use 4 cores? Because very few games do.

Comment: @kotekzot when I play BF4 Beta, the activity on my quad CPU jumps to 80%+ over all cores. This may be due to poor optimisation, but with the high specs of BF4 I would say a quad core is a must. And a six-or-oct core if you want to run all on reccomended, according to the BF4 spec sheet.

Comment: @kotekzot: the *official* recommended setup is Intel quad-core or AMD hexa-core. http://images.vg247.com/current//2013/09/Bf4SPECSvg.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sounds very much like the CPU is your culprit. Similar  for me (Core 2 Quad 3 GHz). I'm able to pick pretty much any graphics setting on my GTX 680 without significantly influencing my frame rate (except when using oversized rendering like 200%).

Although keep in mind that the current beta is most likely a not optimized debug build; so performance might (and most likely will) still increase quite a bit for the official release.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I've switched from [Athlon II X2 245e](http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=681) to [i5 3550](http://ark.intel.com/products/65516), while keeping same graphics card, which is [HD7750 (factory OC'd to 880MHz)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4131#sp). AFAIK, this GPU performs slightly worse in BF3/BF4 than your GTX650. After change of CPU frame-rate in BF3 improved drastically, and BF4beta is playable at 1920x1200.